# iOS 8: Region Monitoring, how to make it work

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-location

Here's the code snippet. Below.

```
// Initialize the region with the Estimote iBeacon manually generated UUID of 16 bytes size.
NSUUID *estimoteUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:[Repository getiBeaconRegionUUID]];
_beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:estimoteUUID
                                                  identifier:@"A"];

// Launch app when display is turned on and inside region.
_beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

// Create a location manager
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
// Set delegate
_locationManager.delegate = self;
if ([CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]])
{
    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    [_locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:_beaconRegion];

    // Get status update right away for UI
    [_locationManager requestStateForRegion:_beaconRegion];
}
else
    NSLog(@"This device does not support monitoring beacon regions");
```

There is the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` added to the app. plist.

There was never the dialog with the text from the key above.

In Settings => Privacy => Location Services for the app. was turned off after the first app. run.

The delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state
              forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

is never called.

In iOS 7 the same app. worked without the authorization request.

Share your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I added `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key-value pair into `InfoPlist.strings` it showed the dialog and started to work.

Answer (score 1):

i have face same problem when i migrate to ios8 from ios7.and i have done following way with the apple doc with explanation of mine.

Check What apple says Here :

[APPLE DOC](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html)

from iOS 8, `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or a `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key value in `Info.plist` file is required.but also you need to request permission from the user before you registering for location updates, either by calling `[_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]` or `[_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` choose any of above as per you requirement.

please note this info it will gonna help through out ios 8.

Comment: The dialog for requestAlwaysAuthorization does not appear. In settings for location services the app. appears with 2 variants: Never and Always, but for Always there is no description below. I expect there to be NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription value.